# Breaking out of a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a storyboard designated to logging into my app. I have this embedded in a UINavigationController. After logging into my app (and transitioning to a new storyboard), I want to "break out" of this Navigation Controller (i.e. after I log in, I no longer want to be able to go back to the login screen). I do *not* want to replace the Navigation Controller with another Navigation Contoller - once I hit this point, I would like no Navigation Controller at all.

How is the best way to handle this? Thanks!

FYI: Using Swift 3

Comment: You can use: `[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]` OR you can just leave the login controller on the stack and `present` your main controller with some custom animation. I prefer the second option because when you need to log out, you can just pop all the way back.. I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I have done this in my app is to have a Navigation controller for the authentication part, then another Navigation Controller for the main app.

So once my users have logged in, I will replace the root view controller with the new navigation controller and set the initial VC to display:

```
APIClient.authenticate(username, password) { result in 
   if result, let appDelegate = UIApplication.delegate as? AppDelegate {]
      let mainNav = MainNavigationController()
      let mainVC = MainViewController()
      mainNav.setViewControllers([mainNav])
      appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainNav
   }
}
```

Then your AuthNavigation controller would be deintialised and the user would not be able to navigate back to the authentication part of the app.

This approach effectively resets your view hierarchy. When you are going through your authentication flow you will be pushing items onto the navigation stack.

Once your Authentication flow is complete the most effective way would be to create a new navigation stack and replace the root controller with this. Then all of the VC's in the old stack will be de-initialised and removed from memory and your new navigation stack wouldn't know anything of them. Putting your new navigation and main app view controller at the top level of it, which is what you want.

Comment: This is the ideal approach for restarting window view hierarchy (which is what you want actually)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice to handle that is to make your login view the root after launch screen (Not included in the Navigation controller), So when you are done with your login process just present your UINavigationController.
This is good in all cases, Your root now is your navigation controller you can not go back to the login screen till you dismiss your navigation controller (you can use it to logout)